# IMAGE_REL_AMD64_SECTION zero or one based?

Tags: windows, linker, portable-executable, coff

Per the Microsoft PE/COFF document, relocation type IMAGE_REL_AMD64_SECTION means "The 16-bit section index of the section that contains the target. This is used to support debugging information."

Normally this would be assumed to be 0-based, but a symbol section number in a PE file is 1-based. Should the section index for IMAGE_REL_AMD64_SECTION relocation be written as 0 or 1 based?

Comment: A lot of your questions can be answered by "see how another linker or compiler does it".

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, I've been running a lot of experiments with the Microsoft toolchain. In this case, I don't know how to get the compiler to generate a relocation of that type; if I knew that, I could probably answer the original question by experiment.

Comment: I don't know either.  We've been through this before, either you ask for help from Microsoft or you ask for help from programmers that want to use your open-source tool.  I know you are pursuing the latter, pretty easy to get help when you stop trying to be the one-guy-guru.  So your problem is simply solved with "i-dont-know-code".  Return E_NOTIMPL and make sure that you'll get your hands on it when it blows.  With non-zero odds that somebody will fix it for you, the open source way.